# W10 - does not boot

Tags: windows-10, boot

After some updates my W10 installation will not boot. At the very beginning there is a black screen and it says: Loading Windows but nothing happens.

I've got my Windows 7 installation DVD (from which it was upgraded to Windows 10). Can I repair the Windows 10 installation with Win7 DVD?

I've backed up all the data - I just want to get it boot (and probably do a factory reset)

Comment: Chances are high that your windows updated the graphics card driver to a newer but faulty version, which means windows actually boot but you can't see your desktop.No, you can't repair windows 10 using windows 7 installation disk.

Comment: You can use Media Creation Tool to download ISO of w10 to repair your instalation... https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10